# Excel VBA Format function return unexpected value with "1A", "1P"

Tags: vba, format

I would like to write some string codes into excel cells, below is the sample script:

```
Sub Write2DigitCode()

    Dim aryCode(), i As Long
    
   aryCode = Array("1B", "1A", "10", "42", "03", "04", "1N", "1P", "1J", "02", "07")
    With ActiveSheet.[A1]
        .Value = "with_format_func"
        .Offset(, 1).Value = "expected"
        
        For i = LBound(aryCode) To UBound(aryCode)
            .Offset(i + 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            .Offset(i + 1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            
            '**** method 1: user Format function directly
            .Offset(i + 1).Value = Format(aryCode(i), "00")
            
            '**** method 2: use IsNumeric to distinguish code without digits
            If IsNumeric(aryCode(i)) Then
                .Offset(i + 1, 1).Value = Format(aryCode(i), "00")
            Else
                .Offset(i + 1, 1).Value = aryCode(i)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    Erase aryCode

End Sub
```

`Method 2` got what I need, `Method 1` got two unexpected values with "1A", "1P":

```
with_format_func    expected
1B  1B
00  1A
10  10
42  42
03  03
04  04
1N  1N
01  1P
1J  1J
02  02
07  07
```

[image]

The result means `Format("1A", "00") = "00"` and `Format("1P", "00") = "01"`. It makes no sense.

Shouldn't return itself when the code contains letters? Any comments or replies would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numbers with postfix A or P, the format function translates the number to an hour of the day. The return value is the percent of the day (ie. 12PM = 50%). Formatting with double zero ("00") rounds the value to an integer: AM = 0, PM = 1

```
Debug.Print "12A" & "   " & Format("12A", "00.00") & "   " & Format("12A", "00")
Debug.Print " 6A" & "   " & Format( "6A", "00.00") & "   " & Format( "6A", "00")
Debug.Print "12P" & "   " & Format("12P", "00.00") & "   " & Format("12P", "00")
Debug.Print " 6P" & "   " & Format( "6P", "00.00") & "   " & Format( "6P", "00")
```

Output

```
12A   00.00   00
 6A   00.25   00
12P   00.50   01
 6P   00.75   01
```